# Docker Compose Two Applications Init DB

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have two entities.
My asp.net application and the database from where it takes it's data.

My Dockerfile is following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
COPY bin/Debug/net6.0/ ./
COPY /DBinit.sql ./
COPY /entrypoint.sh ./
WORKDIR ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Server.dll"]
EXPOSE 80/tcp
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

My entrypoint.sh is following:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
run_cmd="dotnet run --server.urls http://*:80"

until dotnet ef database update; do
>&2 echo "SQL Server is starting up"
sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "SQL Server is up - executing command"
$run_cmd

sleep 30s
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Your_password123 -d master -i /DBinit.sql
```

And my Docker Compose is:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Your_password123"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

My application is running correctly. Both server_db and server_web are up.
My issue, is that the db itself is empty and my DBinit.sql script is not getting executed.

From where I can see. My problem is that this DBinit.sql file is not getting copied inside the server_db.
If I will open up the ls -la of the / in server_web. This init script is there (but it shouldn't even be as part of my web app)

While if I will do the same inside server_db. There is no sql script in it.
And I am getting really confused with all of these Docker entities.

Could someone point me to a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd` from your asp.net container.
I recommend you to do the next:

1. Create separate `Dockerfile` for your DB (name it `Dockerfile.db`) and remove related from your app's `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
COPY /DBinit.sql /
COPY /db_entrypoint.sh /
WORKDIR /
# you may chmod db_entrypoint.sh on your host system so you will not need this line at all
RUN chmod +x /db_entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /db_entrypoint.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

2. Move DB-related stuff to another entrypoint (let's name it `db_entrypoint.sh`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30s
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P "$SA_PASSWORD" -d master -i /DBinit.sql
```

(note that I've replaced `Your_password123` with env variable)

3. Prepare your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.db
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Your_password123"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

That's all. Check it out — now you may be able to init your DB successfully